# How to get the length of Row in FlinkSQL?

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

sql: `CREATE TABLE tab1 ( data Row<id BIGINT,name VARCHAR>) WITH ...;`

I want to know the length of Row , such as :
     `select length(data) as size from tab1...` 
the output length is 2.

How can I do it?

Comment: I want to get the number of columns instead of the number of rows

Answer (score 2):

The `Row` type has a `getArity()` method that you could use, either directly in the Table API, or by wrapping it in a user-defined function for use in SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming FlinkSQL uses normal SQL , you could try doing

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as size FROM tab1;
```

Comment: This will basically calculate the number of rows in the table not the number of columns.

Comment: Yes, I want to get the number of columns instead of the number of rows